# JS find difference between to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I have this situation where I get a array of object form a server like this

```
serverData = [
   {
   drive: car,
   employe: {
      name: Doe,
      firstName: John
      },
   salary: 123
   },
   {
   drive: boat,
   employe: {
      name: Kirby,
      firstName: Eva
      },
   salary: 678
   },
   {
   drive: moto,
   employe: {
      name: Bond,
      firstName: James
      },
   salary: 555
   }]
```

and an array of data edited in the frontend

```
frontData = [
   {
   drive: boat,
   employe: {
      name: Kirby,
      firstName: Eva
      },
   salary: 678
   },
   {
   drive: car,
   employe: {
      name: Doe,
      firstName: John
      },
   salary: 432
   },
   {
   drive: bus,
   employe: {
      name: tata,
      firstName: toto
      },
   salary: 456
   },
]
```

How to get the difference of this two array so I can post, update or delete object on my server. (as you can see I have no attribute to rely on as each one could be update...)

So I need to know:

- which object is on server and not on frontEnd => delete
- which object is on frontEnd and not on server => post
- which object has change => update

i.e
delete "james bond"
post "tata toto"
update "John Doe"

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the overall approach? Why don't just create an object `const changes = { post: [], update: [], delete: [] };` and `.push()` to appropriate array an object directly on change event? I mean something like this `updateBtn.onclick = () => changes.update.push({ ... });` and next `deleteBtn.onclick = () => changes.delete.push({ ... });` and so on

Comment: Without an id and the given information it's impossible to make a difference between a new, deleted or updated entry. Either add an id to your objects or provide more information about your scenario.

Comment: For your case it might work if you ignore that objects can be updated, instead consider every change as a deletion or addition. With this approach you could compare each object in `frontData` with each object in `serverData`: if there is no match it needs to be removed/added